# Deleting Series entries if they are stop-words

Tags: python, pandas, series, stop-words

I want to take a series of words and their frequency, delete the entries with common stopwords and then write it to a .txt file:

```
f= open('frequ_words.txt', 'w+')

frequ_words = pd.Series(' '.join(df['message']).lower().split()).value_counts()[:500]

stop_words = get_stop_words('de')

for i in stop_words:
        try:
            frequ_words.drop(i)
        except:
            pass

f.write(str(frequ_words))

f.close()
```

I tried also other ways to loop this, such as:

```
for i in frequ_words:
    if i in stop_words:
        pass
    else:
        f.write(frequ_words)

f.close()
```

But I cannot get this to work. Suggestions?

EDIT:

The series data looks something like this:

```
word1     89086
word2     85946
...
word500    1098
```

Comment: Are you using `get_stop_words` from the `python-stop-words` package (https://github.com/Alir3z4/python-stop-words)? What are the exact contents of `stop_words` and `frequ_words`? For example, it would be super helpful to see the output of `print(frequ_words.head())`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a series of word frequencies, where the series' index is the words themselves, you can filter for stop words using a single Pandas expression: `words = words[words.index.values != stop_words.values]`.

Here's an example using a series that is similar in appearance to the sample you pasted in above:

```
words = pd.Series(data = [89086, 85946, 1098], index = ['word1', 'word2', 'word500'])

word1      89086
word2      85946
word500     1098
dtype: int64
```

And then if you have another series that contains the stop words as its values:

```
stop_words = pd.Series(data=['word2'])

0    word2
dtype: object
```

To filter the word frequency series so that the stop words are excluded, you'd run this line of code:

```
words = words[words.index.values != stop_words.values]
```

Which outputs your original word frequency series, but with stopwords removed:

```
word1      89086
word500     1098
dtype: int64
```